# Why are directory permissions preventing "sudo apt install" using a file?

Tags: apt, dpkg, lubuntu

I have found that using

```
sudo apt install ./<package_name_here>.deb
```

fails with

```
E: Failed to fetch file:<path_to_package>/<package_name_here>.deb File not found - <path_to_package>/<package_name_here>.deb (13: Permission denied)
```

when a containing directory of `./<package_name_here>.deb` has permissions set to 700.

However, there is no issue when using

```
sudo dpkg -i ./<package_name_here>.deb
```

Is this a bug of `apt` or am I doing something wrong?

---

- lubuntu 20.04
- apt 2.0.2 (amd64)
- dpkg 1.19.7 (amd64)

Comment: Can the user that ran `sudo apt install …` access this file?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes. If not wouldn't the `dpkg` version also fail?

Comment: No idea. I had an idea and thought that this test may shed some light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 1.1, `apt` uses an unprivileged user (`_apt`) to download packages. This includes local package retrieval, unless (in theory) the package isn’t world-readable; there have been bugs with this in the past (see [#805069](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=805069)), this could be a variant...

You can disable this by setting `APT::Sandbox::User` to `root`:

```
apt -o APT::Sandbox::User=root ...
```

Comment: Configuring the sandbox user with the install command worked!
It doesn't even need to be set to root. In my case, the user was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that `apt` and `dpkg` are not the same?

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is used to locate the desired packages in apt-get (as in apt).

Comment: `apt` can install packages from local files, using the syntax shown in the question.